# Auto find file parameter in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've been trying to construct a method for bash to auto complete a file argument. so when you type `vi not[tab][tab]` it auto completes to notes.md if it is within the history or path or gives a list of files when not. I could not figure out how to do this with bash_autocomplete but was able to create the following function that works by executing `x vi not[enter]`. Anyone know how to translate this into auto complete:

```
function x () {
    # last arg is file to find
    FILEARG=${@: -1}
    read -a FILES <<< $(timeout -k 1s 1s \
            find . -maxdepth 4 -name "*${FILEARG}*" -type f \
            -printf "%A@ %p\n"  | sort -nr | awk '{print $2}')
            #A@ access time epoc timestamp
            #C@ status change time
    # use this to only take latest:
    #FILES="${FILES[0]}"

    if [ ${#FILES[@]} -gt 1 ]; then
            select FILE in ${FILES[@]}; do
                    break
            done
    else
            FILE="${FILES[0]}"
    fi

    echo $FILE

    eval ${@:1:$#-1} $FILE
}
```